# Facebook Changed App to Sandbox Mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

Facebook has changed my app to sandbox mode and noone can use the app except developers. 
How can I fix it? When it turned into sandbox mode I met the requirements like creating description and icons and images for app, but its status is pending to be reviewed.
App was for a website in production mode!!!
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can anytime [disable](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) the sandbox mode in the App settings.